# Is it possible to have raw ngs data to practice

Tags: genetics, bioinformatics, human-genetics

I'm looking for raw human ngs data to practice in bioinformatics. Better if it is from different machines (illumina, roche, pacsbio, etc). Panels, exomes and genomes.
Anyone knows something?

Comment: Yeah. Look at [GEO](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/) and [SRA.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sra). You'll find tons of data.

Comment: You can also find it in the supplemental data sections of papers you're interested in.

Comment: yes, thank you. But there I found mostly trimmed and refined data. I'm looking for very raw data, meaning as the files exit from the sequencer. I want to practice with bioinformatics and so I need file as much raw as I can obtain.

Comment: Like fastq formatted files originating from the different technologies... on NCBI/EBI there are files, but their identifier is not the original from the machines.

Comment: This question was asked somewhere and nicely answered. You might find lot of examples of .bam files. see https://www.biostars.org/p/45320/

Answer (score 1):

At least PacBio do provide some example datasets on their [DevNet](https://github.com/PacificBiosciences/DevNet/wiki/Datasets) resource. You should be able to get a lot of different Illumina data from the public data in [BaseSpace](https://basespace.illumina.com/datacentral). I am not sure where to look for official samples from Roche 454, but I wouldn't bother too much as it is discontinued anyway. Rather go for MinIon or IonTorrent data, if you want more.